# Opening 4 instances of specific form only

Tags: c#, winforms

OK... I have searched the internet all over, but maybe I'm typing something wrong or I don't know. Any case, what I have is two windows Forms (I'm coding in C#). Form1 and Form2. In Form1 I have one button. This button, when clicked on, opens Form2. I'm using:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();
```

I WANT to use frm2.Show because I do want to open more than one instance of this form.

The thing now is that I only want to open 4 instances of this form.

If I click on Form1's button, it should open it. Lets say I clicked it 3 times, then Form2 should open 3 times. When I close 2 of them, I now only have 1 left. Then click it 3 times again, and the 4th time it should not open Form2.

Is there some way of knowing how many instances of the form there is? Because an

```
if statement
```

will not do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Application.OpenForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property to check the count of opened forms. Something like.

```
int formCount = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Count(r => r.Name == "Form2");
if (formCount > 4)
    Console.WriteLine("Already 4 instances of the forms are open");
```

Comment: AHHH, there's nothing as good as a quick solve. Thank you:). When my rep becomes 15+ I'll vote. Thanks again.